# Database-schema design for e-commerce website

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am making an E-Commerce website using MySQL. Please let me know the possible flaw in design or other problems. The products have variation in finish and dimensions.

- Product A can have 1 or more variations (1.AA matt finish, AB wood finish, AC oil finish).
- Each variation can have 0 or more dimensions (AA can come in 30x40 and 40x60).
- Each product has their unique property (product A can have thickness, product B can have class).
- The SKU and price of a product depends on all its different properties.

For the unique property I could have used EAV but instead went with this :

[image]

- `Brands`, `Category` and `Collections` are what they say.
- `base_relation_table` is the relation between above 3 tables, all possible combinations.
- `Product` contains all products (Product A, Product B) and reference `ID` of `base_relation_table` to which combination it belongs. It also references `Pattern` which contain its look (stone, woodgrain etc.).
- `product_option_relation` is a relation for unique property (Product A ID, Thickness ID).
- `option_table` contains only the name (thickness, class, printing technology etc.).
- `option_value` contains all values of the option_tables (0.7, 0.9, Professional, Beginners, etc.).
- `product_variant` contains all variations of products (AA, AB, AC, BA, BB, etc).
- `color,finish` are 1:n with product variants (AA matt red, AB shine white).
- `Dimensions` contains n:m relation with `product_variant`.
- `variant_values` is the combination of all properties, all its variations and unique properties.

Schema :

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Catelogue
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema Catelogue
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `Catelogue` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`brands`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`brands` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`brands` (
  `ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `b_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `thumbnails` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`categorys`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`categorys` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`categorys` (
  `ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `c_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `thumbnails` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`collections`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`collections` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`collections` (
  `ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `co_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `thumbnails` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`base_Relation_table`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`base_Relation_table` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`base_Relation_table` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Brands_ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Categorys_ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Collections_ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  INDEX `fk_base_Relation_table_Brands_idx` (`Brands_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_base_Relation_table_Categorys1_idx` (`Categorys_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_base_Relation_table_Collections1_idx` (`Collections_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_base_Relation_table_Brands`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Brands_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`brands` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_base_Relation_table_Categorys1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Categorys_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`categorys` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_base_Relation_table_Collections1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Collections_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`collections` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`pattern`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`pattern` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`pattern` (
  `ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `option_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `values_UNIQUE` (`option_name` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`product`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`product` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`product` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `p_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `Description` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `base_Relation_table_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `pattern_ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  INDEX `fk_Product_base_Relation_table1_idx` (`base_Relation_table_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `name_UNIQUE` (`p_name` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Product_pattern1_idx` (`pattern_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Product_base_Relation_table1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`base_Relation_table_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`base_Relation_table` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Product_pattern1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pattern_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`pattern` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`colors`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`colors` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`colors` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `color_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`option_table`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`option_table` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`option_table` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `option_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `values_UNIQUE` (`option_name` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`option_values`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`option_values` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`option_values` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Option_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `value_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `Option_ID`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `values_UNIQUE` (`value_name` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Option_values_Options1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Option_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`option_table` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`finish`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`finish` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`finish` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `finish_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`product_variant`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`product_variant` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`product_variant` (
  `Variant_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Product_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Finish_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Colors_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `metadata` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `thumbnail` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '\" \"',
  INDEX `fk_ProductDetails_Finish1_idx` (`Finish_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_ProductDetails_Colors1_idx` (`Colors_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Product_Variant_Product1_idx` (`Product_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Variant_ID`, `Product_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ProductDetails_Finish1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Finish_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`finish` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ProductDetails_Colors1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Colors_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`colors` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Product_Variant_Product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`product` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`product_option_relation`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`product_option_relation` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`product_option_relation` (
  `Product_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Option_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_Product_Option_Product1_idx` (`Product_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Product_Option_Options1_idx` (`Option_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Product_ID`, `Option_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Product_Option_Product1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`product` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Product_Option_Options1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Option_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`option_table` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`dimensions`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`dimensions` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`dimensions` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `dimensions_value` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`dimensions_has_product_variant`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`dimensions_has_product_variant` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`dimensions_has_product_variant` (
  `Dimensions_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Product_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Variant_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Dimensions_ID`, `Product_ID`, `Variant_ID`),
  INDEX `fk_Dimensions_has_Product_Variant_Product_Variant1_idx` (`Product_ID` ASC, `Variant_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Dimensions_has_Product_Variant_Dimensions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Dimensions_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`dimensions` (`ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Dimensions_has_Product_Variant_Product_Variant1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_ID` , `Variant_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`product_variant` (`Product_ID` , `Variant_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `Catelogue`.`variant_value`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Catelogue`.`variant_value` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Catelogue`.`variant_value` (
  `Product_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Option_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Value_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Dimensions_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Variant_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `price` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `SKU` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Product_ID`, `Option_ID`, `Value_ID`, `Dimensions_ID`, `Variant_ID`),
  INDEX `fk3_option_values_idx` (`Value_ID` ASC, `Option_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk2_product_options_idx` (`Product_ID` ASC, `Option_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_variant_value_dimensions_has_product_variant1_idx` (`Dimensions_ID` ASC, `Variant_ID` ASC, `Product_ID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk2_product_options`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Product_ID` , `Option_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`product_option_relation` (`Product_ID` , `Option_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk3_option_values`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Value_ID` , `Option_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`option_values` (`ID` , `Option_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_variant_value_dimensions_has_product_variant1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Dimensions_ID` , `Variant_ID` , `Product_ID`)
    REFERENCES `Catelogue`.`dimensions_has_product_variant` (`Dimensions_ID` , `Variant_ID` , `Product_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Is there anything I'm missing? Will it scale? Does it look good?

Comment: Looks OK to me at first sight. But if there are shortcomings - you will only start seeing them when you begin to create reports. If you start feeling that report queries are getting too complex to build - then perhaps you are facing a flaw in the data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "over-normalized".  For example, look at `colors`.  You are replacing a 3-byte 'red' with a 4-byte integer.  No space savings.  (Ok, "magenta" takes more than 4 bytes, but not much.)

The other purpose for normalizing is to make it easier to change the spelling for "red" throughout the dataset.  I don't think that will happen.

So...  Have columns for the "common" or "important" or "commonly searched on" attributes.

For other attributes, toss them into a JSON string and make it a column called, say, `other_attributes`.

Though your schema is more complex than the common EAV, here is a discussion of why EAV is poor and what to do about it:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

As for `dimensions`, think about what you will do with the value or list of values.  I suspect you don't do anything with `"30x40,40x60"` other than display that list on the screen.  It is inherently un-searchable.  So the only practical thing is to put that string inside the JSON that I suggested.

Comment: for the color I do have lots for other name which are a combinations for words such as "light yellow","light green" and so on. And I didn't get the common table part what do you mean by that?  as for dimension i'm planning of sorting my products based of different dimensions . I'll suerly try the JSON string you suggested for other_attributes.

Comment: @Seeon - "Dark cornflower blue".  In `product_variant`, have `color VARCHAR(..)` instead of `color_id`; then toss the table `colors`.  Then, `SELECT ... ORDER BY color` without needing to `JOIN`.

Comment: got it . But I was wondering as I have more than 3k products will this be right approach in terms of storage and thank you for replying I replying appreciate it.

Comment: @Seeon - If you had 100M products, your storage concern would be worth taking into consideration.  With only 3K, I would not get concerned about an extra, say, 10KB.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much you have changed your database, i think table for dimension has to be expanded. You have to add at least couple more tables like price calculation table for Finish, Color based on dimension. You have also not added Customer ,Cart , payment, shipping tables , Tax tables.
If you did then please let me know.